# Is there a way to use a variable as part of a value when setting state from props in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am very new to React. I am trying to make a reusable Checkbox component. These checkboxes are to send info to an API. 
I have a `GET` command on `App.JS`, to set state.

Here is a simplified version of my API

```
{
 "devices":[
   {
    "id":1,
    "valveA": true,
    "valveB": false,
    "valveC": true,
   },
   {
    "id":2,
    "valveA": false,
    "valveB": true,
    "valveC": false,
   }

 ]
}
```

I pass the props to the children like so:

```
render() {
    const {devices} = this.state;
    return (       
          <div >
            {devices.map(device => (
              <Device device={device} key={device.id} />
            ))}
          </div>     
    );
```

I can make individual components for each checkbox and setting the `checked` state by setting individual state like so:

```
 state = { checked: this.props.device.valveA }
```

But that means I have to make a component for each 'valve' in my API. Ideally I would like to have one Checkbox component that I can reuse for all my "valves".

I've made a semi-working component by specifying the name of the valve as a prop:

```
<Device device={device} key={device.id} switchFor="valveA" />
```

And here is my component that successfully passes the change to the API, however I need to dynamically set the last part of the setState

```
this.props.device.{{{I WANT THIS TO BE DYNAMIC}}}
```

, otherwise all switches just get the state of valveA:

```
state = { checked: false };

  componentDidMount(){

    this.setState({ checked: this.props.device.valveStatus })
  }


  handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    const type = this.props.switchFor;

    const checkedStatus = event.target.checked;

    const deviceID = this.props.device.id;

    const obj = {};
    obj[type] = checkedStatus;

    this.setState({ checked: checkedStatus });

    axios
      .patch(`http://localhost:3001/devices/${deviceID}`, obj)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { device } = this.props;
    const theFor = this.props.switchFor + device.id;
    return (
      <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="custom-control-input"
          id={theFor}
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
        />
        <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={theFor}>
          toggle
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Sorry if my code is kind of janky, I am very new to React.

I am not sure if I am moving in the right direction, somehow I have a feeling that there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: It'd help a lot if you could describe what you're trying to do better, and maybe try including all of the code, for example `class Device extends React.Component{...` so we know what code is for what component

Comment: no, maybe you're a bit distant... don't use the same state for the checked status... can you try to share a running example at https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation isn't really quite clear, but I think I can KIND OF understand what you're trying to do. If I'm wrong, just ignore me. So it seems like you want to be able to change which valve/switch of the device object to be displayed by your  component. If that's the case, simply set that as a state. Off the top of my head, I can think of using a an array that mirrors your "devices" array:

```
this.state = {
    "devices":[
       {
        "id":1,
        "valveA": true,
        "valveB": false,
        "valveC": true,
       },
       {
        "id":2,
        "valveA": false,
        "valveB": true,
        "valveC": false,
       }
    ],
    "selectedValve": ["valveA", "valveB"]
}
```

Then when rendering your Device components, just do:

```
render() {
    const {devices} = this.state;
    return (       
          <div >
            {devices.map((device, ind) => (
              <Device device={device} key={device.id} switchFor={this.state.selectedValve[ind]} />
            ))}
          </div>     
    );
}
```

To change the valve of a particular device, you can have:

```
handleSwitchChange(deviceInd, newValve){
    let copySelectedValve = [...this.state.selectedValve];
    copySelectedValve[deviceInd] = newValve;

    this.setState({
        selectedValve: copySelectedValve;
    })
}
```

To change the first device to valveB, you'd just do handleSwitchChange(0, "valveB");
To change the true/false of a valve of a device, you can write something like: